# Adhoc network to do p2p communication in ubuntu machines

Tags: 16.04, networking, network-manager

I need to do peer to peer communication between my 2 ubuntu 16.04 machines. 
I created an ad-hoc network in 2 laptops.
In the Wi-Fi settings tab, I gave SSID name as Ad-hoc and I changed the mode to Ad-hoc. Remaining things i havent touched.
Then in the Wi-Fi security tab, i gave WEP 128-bit pharaphrase and i assigned a 
key for that.
Then in the IPV4 seetings tab, i gave a fixed IP address and subnet mask and gateway.
And atlast I saved all and i closed. But I am not able to connect to that adhoc network. Can anyone help me to fix this?

Also, if I tried to create adhoc networks in 2 machines using command terminal, am able to ping between 2 computers but am not able to access the internet. Can anyone help me to figure out how we can use adhoc and wifi at the same time in a laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Most laptops can only be connected to one network at a time, and that network in your case is the network between the 2 pcs, to access the internet you need to be connected to router (other network), simply with reference to my knowledge, you can't.

I'm a network and security engineer.